# Nodemon installation failing

Tags: node.js, npm, backend, nodemon

When I run npm install -g Nodemon I get an access error saying I should run a chown command which I have done. Despite doing this it still will not work can someone help? The error also says something is wrong with he cache.

I tried running the command It is telling me to run and that hasnt worked, I have also checked the path. I have uninstalled Node and NPM, then reinstalled but that didn't fix it either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Perhaps nodemon is already installed and currently running, so you can't overwrite it? Check the running processes or restart your computer.

Comment: @CherryDT When I try to run it says zsh: command not found: nodemon

Comment: Ok can you please include the full log from. npm in your question?

Comment: @CherryDT I have solved the problem by adding "start": "npx Nodemon index.js", into the scripts bit of the package.json file. Thank you so much for trying to help :)